# how to use values_list in Django to show one column from the table

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have three models user, usecase, and user_assign

I have list of users in the database assigned to specific usecase in the user_assign table.

I'm trying to show the user names not the emails assigned to specific usecase.

Result I'm trying to get:
SELECT user_email FROM `usecase_assign` WHERE `usecase_id` LIKE 'NN245';

my models:

```
class UsecaseAssign(models.Model):
   usecase_assign_date = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
   usecase = models.ForeignKey(Usecase, models.DO_NOTHING)
   user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')

class Usecase(models.Model):
   usecase_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
   usecase_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
   usecase_type = models.ForeignKey('UsecaseType', models.DO_NOTHING)
   kpi = models.ForeignKey(Kpi, models.DO_NOTHING)

class User(models.Model):
   user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
   user_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my views.py:

```
@user_login_required
def view_usecase_details(request,ucid):
   usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid).all()
   if request.method == "GET":
       usecase_assigned = UsecaseAssign.objects.values_list('user_email').filter(usecase_id=ucid).values()
       context = {'usecase_details': usecase_details, "users": User.objects.all(), 'usecase_assigned':usecase_assigned}
       return render(request, 'UsecaseDetails.html', context)
```

my template:

```
<div class="card card-body shadow-sm mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <form action="/usecase-details/{{usecase_details.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row mb-4">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
            <label class="h6" for="user_email">Assign Users:</label>
            <select name="user" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="user">
                <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                {% for user in users %}
                <option value="{{ user.user_email }}">{{ user.user_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}                             
              </select>                          
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Changes">
      </form>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-0 border-bottom">
            <div>
                <p class="pe-4">Assigned users:</p>
                {% for user in usecase_assigned %}
                <p class="pe-4">{{user.user_name}}</p>
                {% endfor %}                             
            </div>          
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get values from related objects like: `usecase_assigned = UsecaseAssign.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid).values_list('user_email__user_name')`. I think it should also work from `User` like `User.objects.filter(usercaseassign__usecase_id=ucid).values_list('user_name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get usecase assigned users username you can make the following query:

```
usecase_assigned = UsecaseAssign.objects.select_related('user_email').values_list('user_email__username').filter(usecase_id=ucid)
```

> select_related('user_email') - Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).